# Callback при использовании .trigger() Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

У меня есть ряд навешанных триггеров по клику. Клики в свою очередь вызывают другие методы и функции, в том числе и асинхронные. И бывают моменты, когда кто-то раньше другого вызывается.

```
$('.js-block_1').trigger('click');
$('.js-block_2').trigger('click');
$('.js-block_3').trigger('click');
```

Не подскажете, как можно сделать Callback ? По документации `.trigger` не имеет CallBack.

Приходила идея с промисами, но не могу понять куда все это прописывать, ведь тут просто клики. Спасибо!

Comment: Эм.. И у кого что не воспроизводится? Есть обработчики событий, которые вызывают асинхронные функции, например, ajax. Ему нужно последовательно вызвать несколько таких обработчиков, но так, чтобы к моменту вызова следующего обработчика, асинхронные операции предыдущего завершились.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача мутная, ответ абстрактный. Надеюсь я правильно вас понял.

```js
$('#box').click(function(){
  alert('Click box!');
});


function callbackTrigger(){alert('Trigger setup!')};


setTimeout(function(){
  $('#box').trigger( "click", callbackTrigger());
}, 3000)
```

```css
#box{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box"></div>
```

Comment: Жуть...​​​​​​​​​

Comment: @Qwertiy согласен:) ennet явно что-то делает не так!

Answer (score 0):

Если асинхронные операции - это ajax, то можно у jQuery подписаться на их завершение.

Если какая-то работа с dom'ом типа отображения диалогов пользователю, можно попытаться применить MutationObserver.

А вообще, ты делаешь что-то не так, раз тебе такое понадобилось.